# DJI Spark - Autonomous flight?

Tags: dji-sdk

I was planning to use DJI Spark drone for some projects and was wondering:

Is it possible to program these drones to do autonomous flights with the mobile SDK?

Answer (score 4):

There is sample code for Missions at 
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/tree/master/Sample%20Code/ObjcSampleCode/DJISdkDemo/Demo/MissionManager

Spark is supported as of the 4.6 release